# How to force Android to tell the browser about real physical resolution?

Tags: screen, browser

Samsung Flow allows users of Samsung phones to use the **external display**, eg. laptop as larger display and also with physical keyboard.

However, the browser is still in mobile mode (big UI and big font on low resolution).

I've activated the **view as desktop** in browser and the websites are displayed as in desktop, but the Android OS is still reporting to browser (or browser itself) the **virtual resolution** which is altered by DPI. Thus the web pages are **limited at around 800px to 900px (width)**. This can be seen when opening mobile browser at *whatismyresolution.com*.

How to force the browser to **use physical resolution in its desktop mode**? I've tried all mobile browsers but no such option in their Settings.

Comment: Change the browsers user agent to something other than a mobile browser

Comment: that agent value is reported to server side, doesn't affect the resolution that browser is using

Comment: You are mistaken. In Edge on the desktop you can change the user agent and make it appear your on a mobile device part of that configuration is also choosing the resolution of the device.

Comment: but also the font, its size if not reducible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The font size setting in **Android Settings** can change the font size and apps will follow but it is still not enough to use the physical resolution

In order to use **physical resolution** on the phone that browser will report physical resolution to the JavaScript inside the pages:

- The font size in default Android Settings is not enough, it's just app UI
- Steps

  - 1. Enable **Developer Settings**, press 7 times on something in Android Settings of that kind of stuff
  - 2. Go inside Developer Settings, set "**Minimum width**" to the smaller size of the dimensions, eg. full HD is 1920x1080, set it to 1080
  - 3. **BUT BE AWARE**: DON'T PUT THAT "Minimum width" TOO BIG, ALL UI IN ANDROID WILL BE TOO SMALL TO PRESS WITH FINGER TO CHANGE IT BACK.